# Bootstrap modal not showing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to show a  bootstrap modal on page load like this

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){                  
          $('#mapModal').modal('show'); 
        });
    </script> 

  <div id="mapModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Seller Location</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Some content 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

There comes a black overlay on the whole page when page loads but  modal  window does not display

**Edit :**

i tried `$(window).load(function (){   });but that also does nothing`

Comment: try using `$(window).load(function() {
 /* code here */
});`

Comment: that does not work even does not give me an alert  dont know why  $(window).load(function() {
                alert('hi');
                 
            });

Answer (score 4):

Try to use lower version of jQuery.

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but
>   lower than version 3

Answer (score 1):

I got Your error solution you just use bootstrap verion 3.3.1

Use :

CSS : -- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

JS -- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

And Jquery Version -- code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js