# Bootstrap 3.3.6 and JQuery 3.1.0 not compatible?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, compatibility

Is it possible that these 2 (both are newest versions) aren't compatible?
(In the snippets: The local files are the newest versions, the online retrieved files are older versions)
Is there anything I can do to use both locally?

These snippets work:

Snippet 1:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Snippet 2:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This snippet doesn't work:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I've tried them with this dropdown menu:

```
<nav class="nav navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Info<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="html/bussen.html">Bussen</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/DJs.html">DJ's</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: use the default bundle which comes when you download the bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal not showing on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586047/bootstrap-modal-not-showing-on-page-load)

Answer (score 13):

Right Now **Bootstrap 3.3.7** are Updated and jquery **jquery-3.1.1** are well working for me. Not showing a single error in my console or anywhere.
So I think you can use updated bootstrap.

Bootstrap say to set JQuery version to **1.9.0** or **higher** [Link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included)

**Bootstrap 3.3.7 support jQuery version 3 and above**

Get more information in Github Issue [Link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834)

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap 3 is not compatible with jQuery 3.0 and above at the moment. So latest version of jQuery that can be used with Bootstrap 3 is 2.2.4.

Although, [some](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834#issuecomment-228271973) reported that it works with jQuery Migrate.

You can check [this discussion](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834) for more info.

**Update**

Like MD Ashik reported, latest Bootstrap versions work well with jQuery 3+

Answer (score -3):

Because jQuery 3.0 is still in alpha test, so it needs time to compatible with Bootstrap 3. Y

Comment: Version 3 is not in alpha anymore... In fact 3.1 was released recently https://blog.jquery.com/2016/07/07/jquery-3-1-0-released-no-more-silent-errors/